# What are the views of different political parties on asylum seekers in Australia?

Tags: parties, australia, asylum

What are the views of different political parties on asylum seekers in Australia? (e.g. Labor, Liberal and Greens)

Comment: This question seems very general. As a side note, it was asked on the morning of an election.

Comment: sry,i missed it

Comment: Greens are obviously quite pro-asylum seekers, but I think you'll find that Labor would normally be pro-asylum seekers as well, it's just the popular opinion against them that makes Labor anti-asylum seekers.  Liberal, though, is quite anti-asylum seekers (look at John Howard's government).  This is general observations I've made, hence why I'm posting this as a comment and not an answer.